# add padding between menu items on toggle dropdown menu open

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I need to add space between the li items on my toggle open menu, I can't find the class, I've try to give them padding to the next classes; .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu, .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a, and other more. It doesn't do anything.

Here is the image:

[image: here is the dropdown menu open]

Comment: Please read: "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: @FrankGroot http://blog.gocnetworking.com/ you have to check on mobile versions, when you open the toggle menu the blog and web are too close to each other and I want to separate a little bit, I can't find the clas I've tried all the classes about the open li dropdown menu....

Comment: Try `#menu_my_bootstrap_menu_settings_menugoc2_container ul li { padding: 10px 0; }`

Comment: Or this: `.menu-item-home { padding-bottom: 10px; }`

Comment: @NullDev Excellent!!! perfect!!! I never thought on that!!! Thanks !!!

Comment: Welp, posting as answer then I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [link](http://blog.gocnetworking.com/) you provided, you could easily access the `li` elements by targeting the ID provided by bootstrap and selecting the child elements like this:

```
#menu_my_bootstrap_menu_settings_menugoc2_container ul li { 
    padding: 10px 0; /* Or any other values */
}
```